# Tablespace free on multiple Oracle 12c databases

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I am on operations, and I am trying to implement a way of checking total/free tablespaces on production tablespaces (oracle 12c)

Are there any ideas on how could I implement it?

Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DBA_FREE_SPACE view.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3122.htm#REFRN23076